# How can I get my recovery back?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, restore, asus-zenfone-2

I was trying to get TWRP on my Asus Zenfone 2 ZE551ML (Stock firmware, WW-2.20.40.198). In order to do that, I tried to unlock the bootloader using [this guide](http://URL=%22http://androiding.how/how-to-unlock-bootloader-on-asus-zenfone-2-unofficial-method/%22]). I don't believe the unlocking really worked, though, because every time I tried to flash TWRP through Fastboot or the app, it failed.

It did, however, lose me my stock recovery. If I go to the bootloader and select "RECOVERY MODE", the phone just restarts and goes to the same bootloader again. So I got neither the stock recovery, nor TWRP.

As you can see from [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/149083/131868), the only way I know how to flash stock firmware is through the stock recovery.

I did manage to root and install Xposed, though, both through adb. What worries me, though, is that if some root app or Xposed module mess up my phone somehow, I won't be able to flash stock firmware or a backup. So I really need a recovery. I would actually prefer to have the stock recovery at this point.

What can I do? I need the stock recovery to flash the stock firmware, but I can't.

I've tried Asus Flashtool before, but it didn't work. I think maybe it's because I tried it on Windows 10, some users said it worked better with Windows 7.

How can I get my recovery back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flash the stock recovery through fastboot. The complete guide for flashing is [here](http://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-12528-1-1.html)