# Will flashing stock firmware also restore the stock recovery?

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, asus-zenfone-2

My phone is Asus Zenfone 2 (ZE551ML, Z00AD).

As described in [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/163823/how-can-i-get-my-recovery-back/163830#163830), I was unsuccessfully trying to unlock my bootloader. In the process, I also lost the stock recovery.

I learned how to [flash stock recovery](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163830/131868) to repair it.

My firmware version is **WW-2.20.40.198**. I haven't been able to find the stock recovery file for that exact firmware version. However, I **have** been able to [get a hold of](https://mega.nz/#F!k4MHiAgL!dVuOKeH3eokcwPSNI79ffw) the **WW-2.20.40.196** stock recovery file. I was [told on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com//zenfone2/help/how-recovery-t3514205/post69963268) that this would be fine, so I flashed it via Fastboot.

It seems to be working, although I haven't tried to actually [flash firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149072/how-to-restore-the-stock-firmware-to-the-asus-zenfone-2) through adb yet.

I'm now unsure of which firmware to flash through adb, WW-2.20.40.**196** or WW-2.20.40.**198**.

I have two conflicting ideas.

On the one hand:

1. Since the recovery file I flashed with fastboot was **196**, then perhaps I should also flash the **196** firmware file?

Or maybe:

2. If I flash the **198** file, perhaps it will also restore the **198** stock recovery? In that case, perhaps I can just flash the **198** firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Flashing: Not the rude one, the android one!

honestly, You should flash the 198,to ensue you get the right files. You *might* need to unlock the bootloader again, but I doubt it.

Also, to answer the title: Yes, Flashing the Stock OS will Flash stock recovery. Unlike custom ROMS, Stock ROMS Re-flash the RADIO (Also known as /efs in Samsung, is responsible for mobile data, calls, WiFi, etc.) The system, the recovery, kernel, boot image.... And more!